# Creating a modal window to load data with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to load data inside a modal window using AngularJS but I'm not sure how to do that. I need the url also to change when the link is clicked and the data to load inside a modal window instead of loading a new page.

I have tried using the jQuery Facebox plugin but it doesnt seem to work, I'm also using the twitter bootstrap modal component.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="subnav span12" id="post-main-container" ng-controller="PostsController">
  <div class="btn-group pull-left span5" id="sort-nav">
    <a class="btn active">Popular</a>
    <a class="btn">Recent</a>
    <a class="btn">Favorite</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group pull-right " id="view-nav">
    <a class="btn" id="2col"><i class="icon-th-large"></i></a>
    <a class="btn active" id="4col"><i class="icon-th"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" id="6col"><i class="icon-th-list"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <a id="reload" class="btn"><i class="icon-refresh"></i></a>
    <a class="btn"><i class="icon-random"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid span12" id="img-container">
    <ul class="unstyled" id="image-container">
      <li class="post-container box2" ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <div class="post-btns" style="display:none;">
          <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">Share</a>
          <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">Add</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#/posts/{{post.id}}">
          <img ng-src="{{post.image}}">
        </a>
        <p class="post-snippet" style="display:none;">{{post.description}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to load the `"#/posts/{{post.id}}"` in a modal window.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this will completely solve your problem but we have a directive wrapper of the bootstrap modal on http://angular-ui.github.com/. Because you are defining your divs in your page, the two-way data binding should just work. In regards to the url link to change, I'm not sure why you would want this since this is a modal control.

Angular-ui group has an angularjs replacement of the js for modal and some other bootstrap controls see [here](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/)

--dan

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to facilitate a deep link directly into a modal?  Trello.com does this and it is very useful.

Comment: Modals, well, are modals. In my experience, a modal is shown based on a user's action. I know of one use case, which I've used and that is authentication, which even then, the modal is shown based on user's action of going to unauthenticated page. In the wild world of the web standards change pretty fast. I'll take a look at Trello.com

Answer (score 6):

**The Angular way is view watching the model and you changing the model:**

- Put the dialog into the markup.
- Bind content of the dialog to something like `selectedPost`.
- Clicking the link only change `selectedPost` and hide/show the dialog.

Here is a very quick version:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0fsRUp?p=preview

Checkout [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-modal), they already have a component for Bootstrap's modal.

Comment: I think your plunkr is dead.

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to be using [Twitter BootStrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)'s modal, [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjzabkar/MWAek/1/) keeps the Angular components separate, which allows you to create a partial html file with only your modal's html and properly scoped bindings.

This means you can use an [Angular directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) declaratively in your html:

```
 <a my-popup-directive="partials/myModal.html">Open MyModal</a>
```

**Edit**: Per @DanDoyon's (correct) comment, the directive was renamed to a non-`ng` namespace.
**Update**: Using a [Bootstrap 3 modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) with Angular 1.x makes a custom directive or [angular-ui modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) pretty much unnecessary.

Comment: Just to be clear for those reading, ng-popup is not an angular directive. Using ng for namespace is not incorrect but does imply that its from the core library.

Comment: I've taken a version of this and am building upon it: https://github.com/clouddueling/angularjs-modals

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt to make directives for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/tadchristiansen/gt92r/

Hopefully you find it useful.