# How can I populate Modal data with Angular JS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a modal that opens in Bootstrap currently and want to load it via Angular. I can't use [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) for various reasons, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183414/creating-a-modal-window-to-load-data-with-angular-js), while great, doesn't help.

Currently, I'm loading the modal with:
`<div class="control-btn"><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Load</a></div>`

But that isn't passing the data that I need to the modal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i have been doing.
First, create an angular template that will be your modal popup. Save this as an html file named "modalTemplate.html" somewhere in your website directory.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalTemplate.html">
  <h4>welcome to my modal</h4>
  <div>
    {{someData}}
    {{someOtherData}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Next, create a separate controller to manage this template:

```
MyApp.app.controller("testModalCtrl", ['$scope', 'dialog', 'dataForTheModal', 'otherDataForTheModal',
             function testModalCtrl($scope, dialog, dataForTheModal, otherDataForTheModal) {
    $scope.someData = dataForTheModal;
    $scope.someOtherData = otherDataForTheModal;

    $scope.someActionOnTheModal = function () {
        //do whatever work here, then close the modal
        $scope.dataResultFromTheModal = 'something that was updated' 
        dialog.close(dataResultFromTheModal); // close this modal
    };
}]);
```

Call the modal like so from your original controller:

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
        var d = $dialog.dialog({
            templateUrl: 'modalTemplate.html',
            controller: 'testModalCtrl',
            resolve: {
                dataForTheModal: function () {
                    return 'this is my data';
                },
                otherDataForTheModal: function () {
                    return 'this is my other data';
                }
                //pass as many parameters as you need to the modal                    
            }
        });
        d.open()
            .then(function (dataResultFromTheModal) {
                if (dataResultFromTheModal) {
                    $scope.something = dataResultFromTheModal     
                    /*when the modal is closed, $scope.something will be updated with                     
                    the data that was updated in the modal (if you need this behavior) */
                }
            });
    };
```

For this to work, you also need to inject `$dialog` into your main controller. (just like I have on the testModalCtrl controller above)

Finally, include the template html at the bottom of your page:

```
<div ng-include src="'pathToYourTemplateFile/modalTemplate.html'"></div>
```

I like doing modals like this, because storing each modal as a separate template file keeps things organized and keeps your page markup clean.  Additionally, this makes it easy to re-use modals throughout your app.

Comment: Getting a `Firebug` error: `Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 31-32 ['] in expression [views/modals/myModal.html'].`

Comment: my bad, I left out a single-quote in the ng-include src. See updated answer, it should be src="'.....'"