# How do I get Bootstrap modals to work with AngularJS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to get my Bootstrap modals to work with AngularJS. One modal is

```
    <div id="addToPlaylist" class="modal hide fade" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="addToPlaylistLabel" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>My Modal</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
MODAL BODY
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It adds a song to a playlist the user already has or creates a new playlist. I want to use it with a set of songs, but only have it work with 1 song at a time (for now).

```
<div class="cell" ng-repeat="song in media.data">
</div> <!-- grid-wrapper -->
```

The Angular controller is

```
'use strict';

angular.module('PortalApp')
  .controller('SongsCtrl', function ($scope, MediaService, $location, AudioPlayerAPI, FavoriteService) {

$scope.toggleFaves = function (song) {

  FavoriteService.toggle(song).success(function (response) {
    if (response.successFlag) {
      song.favorite = !song.favorite;        
    }
  });
}    

$scope.fetched = false;

});
```

How do I make this work?

P.S. I don't want jQuery, just the jQuery Lite plugin Angular has.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875095/how-can-i-populate-modal-data-with-angular-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the AngularUI Bootstrap modals (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). Passing data in and out is very easy and it all works the Angular-way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable Angular directive that will hide and show a Bootstrap modal.

```
app.directive("modalShow", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            modalVisible: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            //Hide or show the modal
            scope.showModal = function (visible) {
                if (visible)
                {
                    element.modal("show");
                }
                else
                {
                    element.modal("hide");
                }
            }

            //Check to see if the modal-visible attribute exists
            if (!attrs.modalVisible)
            {

                //The attribute isn't defined, show the modal by default
                scope.showModal(true);

            }
            else
            {

                //Watch for changes to the modal-visible attribute
                scope.$watch("modalVisible", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    scope.showModal(newValue);
                });

                //Update the visible value when the dialog is closed through UI actions (Ok, cancel, etc.)
                element.bind("hide.bs.modal", function () {
                    scope.modalVisible = false;
                    if (!scope.$$phase && !scope.$root.$$phase)
                        scope.$apply();
                });

            }

        }
    };

});
```

Usage Example #1 - this assumes you want to show the modal - you could add ng-if as a condition

```
<div modal-show class="modal fade"> ...bootstrap modal... </div>
```

Usage Example #2 - this uses an Angular expression in the modal-visible attribute

```
<div modal-show modal-visible="showDialog" class="modal fade"> ...bootstrap modal... </div>
```

Another Example - to demo the controller interaction, you could add something like this to your controller and it will show the modal after 2 seconds and then hide it after 5 seconds.

```
$scope.showDialog = false;
$timeout(function () { $scope.showDialog = true; }, 2000)
$timeout(function () { $scope.showDialog = false; }, 5000)
```

I'm late to contribute to this question - created this directive for another question here. [Simple Angular Directive for Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644405/simple-angular-directive-for-bootstrap-modal/19644644#19644644)

Hope this helps.