# angularjs custom twitter bootstrap modal directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

i am trying to create a custom twitter bootstrap modal popup using angularjs Directives. my problem is how can i control the popup from any controller

> ```
> <!-- Modal content-->
> <div class="modal-content">
>   <div class="modal-header">
>     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
>     <h4 class="modal-title">Hello Modal</h4>
>   </div>
>   <div class="modal-body">
>     <p>Modal PopUp</p>
>   </div>
>   <div class="modal-footer">
>     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

and the controller directive is

```
var modal = angular.module('directiveModal', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);



modal.directive('loginModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'directiveTemplate/modal.html',
    link: function(scope,elem,attr)
    {
        elem.bind("click",function()
        {
            console.log("Opening Modal");

        });

    }
  }
});
```

and this is how i have called directive from the init page

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','directiveModal']);


app.config(function($routeProvider) 
{

$routeProvider
.when("/",{
    templateUrl : "template/landing.html",
    controller : "landingCtrl"
})

.when("/home",{
    templateUrl : "template/home.html",
    controller : "homeCtrl"
})
.when("/post",{
    templateUrl : "template/post.html",
    controller : "postCtrl"
})


.otherwise(
{
redirectTo: '/'
});


});
```

How can i control the modal popup 
in html i have it like this.

```
<div login-modal></div>
```

I would like to customize this modal to my need. like if i want have control what text to display. add new elements and call this popup/show on certain conditions are met from the controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Basically inside your directive you need to use standard method from bootstrap.
Something like:

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.title = attrs.title;

    scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
      if(value == true)
        $(element).modal('show');
      else
        $(element).modal('hide');
    });

    $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
      });
    });

    $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
      });
    });
```

As you can see inside the $watch function you have the bootstrap method.
The original answer from which I copied my solution is available here:
[Simple Angular Directive for Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644405/simple-angular-directive-for-bootstrap-modal)